# Article and no article

Tags: articles, adverbs, nouns

> “She is Mr. Rochester’s ward; he commissioned me to find a governess for her. He intended to have her brought up in - shire, I believe.  Here she comes, with her ‘bonne,’ as she calls her nurse.” The enigma then was explained: this affable and kind little widow was no great dame; but a dependant like myself.  I did not like her **the worse** for that; on the contrary, I felt **better** pleased than ever.
>   (Jane Eyre)

There's an article before *worse*, yet none before *better*. Why does the former need an article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Worse* in that case is used as noun, similarly to *better* in "for the better or for the worse" or similarly to "the worse for wear."
*Better* in the other sentence is an adverb, and articles are not used with adverbs.

Comment: As side note, _better_ is also a verb.